# how to detect URL's of FireFox popups

Tags: windows, firefox, logging, popup

I want to log the URLs of all the popup attempts in my FireFox browser running on Windows.

Is there a way to do this? Either somehow externally, or internally with an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Firefox has forced popup makers to get creative with their JavaScript calls, one thing remains the same: in order to open a popup, `window.open` must be called. If you are able to replace that method with a wrapper, you might be able to do it.

As far as modifying the DOM structure on every page that's opened, or just a few, I'd look into the [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) plugin. You can write your own user script (it's just simple JavaScript that executes after the page is loaded).

Comment: Greasemonkey is a good idea. 
I am also interested in logging popups triggered from adware.